# Android studio continuous speech recognition service

Tags: java, android, kotlin

does someone know how to mute the beep of the speech recognition?
I want to create a service in background of continuous speech recognition. I searched anywhere but in all the projects, the service mutes the phone and the music if its running.

Comment: You mean eavesdropping?

Comment: There is no way to do continuous speech recognition.  The beep is there so the user knows you're listening.  You could possibly do it by taking control of the mic and keeping it, but then no other app could use it, and you would of course need to implement your own speech recognition algorithm.  Even if you could mute the beep it wouldn't work like you want, as recognition would constantly turn on and off and miss things in the transitions.  Also it would kill the battery.

Comment: Not eavesdropping, I mean apps like ok google or Siri that are launch when there is a trigger word, but it seems like they are the only app that can do this.